# ¿Cómo generas archivo csv?

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

```
<form method="post" class="form" action="reporte.php">
    <input type="date" name="fecha1">
    <input type="date" name="fecha2">
    <input type="submit" name="generar_reporte">
    </form>
```

Este es el botón para visualizar mi archivo csv, la conexión es pdo desde reporte.php deseo poder ver los datos almacenados en mysql desde este archivo csv

```
<?php
    header('Content-type:application/xls');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=clientes.xls');

    require_once('conexion.php');


?>


?>

<table border="1">
    <tr style="background-color:red;">
        <th>Codigo</th>
        <th>Nombres</th>
        <th>Apellidos</th>
        <th>Telefono</th>
        <th>Ciudad</th>
        <th>Correo</th>

    </tr>
    <?php;

$salida = fopen('saldos.csv', 'w');

if ($salida) {

    $sql = "SELECT codigo, nombres, apellidos,telefono,ciudad,correo FROM clientes";
    $stmt = $dbcon->query($sql);
    $stmt->execute();

    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0 ) {
        while ($fila = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
?>
            <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $salida['codigo']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $salida['nombres']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $salida['apellidos']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $salida['telefono']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $fila['ciudad']; ?></td>
                </tr>   


}
?>
```

Este es el intento que yo he querido realizar para poder gernerar el archivo csv con mysql, soy nuevo únicamente se insertar datos y traer completa la base he visto tutoriales pero al parecer es distinto el proceso cuando la conexión es pdo

el error es el siguiente que me sale en el archivo csv

```
query($sql); $stmt->execute(); if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0 ) { while ($fila = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) ?>
```

mas

> Notice: Undefined variable: salida in C:\xampp\htdocs\crud\reporte.php
>   on line 36 Notice: Undefined variable: salida in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\crud\reporte.php on line 37 Notice: Undefined
>   variable: salida in C:\xampp\htdocs\crud\reporte.php on line 38

Alguien me puede apoyar con el codigo

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! en lugar de $salida (que no veo por ningun lado) sera $fila?

Answer (score 0):

creo que te has liado un poco con el código.

Para empezar, has cerrado dos veces la etiqueta de php poniendo dos veces el cierre `?>`.

Luego abres el archivo "saldos.csv", pero no lo usas, desconozco lo que tienes ahí, pero intuyo que no es necesario.

```php
<?php
    header('Content-type:application/xls');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=clientes.xls');

    require_once('conexion.php');

?>

<table border="1">
    <tr style="background-color:red;">
        <th>Codigo</th>
        <th>Nombres</th>
        <th>Apellidos</th>
        <th>Telefono</th>
        <th>Ciudad</th>
        <th>Correo</th>

    </tr>
<?php

    $sql = "SELECT codigo, nombres, apellidos,telefono,ciudad, correo FROM clientes";
    $stmt = $dbcon->query($sql);
    $stmt->execute();

    while ($fila = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $fila ['codigo'];   ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila ['nombres'];  ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila ['apellidos'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila ['telefono']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila ['ciudad'];   ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila ['correo'];   ?></td>
            </tr>   

<?php
    }
?>
```

Creo que lo que quieres es algo así, ya que al hacer la consulta, te estás trayendo de base de datos la información que necesitas.

El if no lo necesitas porque si no hay filas afectadas el fetch devolverá false, y por tanto no entrará en el while.

En caso de que haya, recorres cada una de las filas y obtienes la información de cada columna accediendo al array con el nombre de la columna y esto lo repites para cada fila, creando así la tabla en HTML.

Un saludo.

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: dbcon in C:\xampp\htdocs\crud\reporte.php on line 22     
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\crud\reporte.php:22 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\crud\reporte.php on line 22

Comment: tengo el problema en el archivo csv

Comment: Hola, si lees detenidamente el error que te da, puedes ver como te dice que en la línea 22 del archivo "C:\xampp\htdocs\crud\reporte.php" estás llamando a la función `query()` de una variable de valor `null` porque la variable `$dbcon` está indefinida. El error no está en el archivo `saldos.csv`. El error está en que no has inicializado la variable `$dbcon`. Esa variable la rebes iniciar de esta manera `$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");` Más info en: [mysqli::query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)